# Expressing chained inequality for each combination of elements of multiple arrays in a concise and scalable way

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization, inequality

I'm having three one-dimensional arrays `a, b, c` of different sizes and I'd like to compute the chained inequality `x < y < z` for each combination `x in a, y in b, z in c`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
b = np.random.randint(100, size=200)
c = np.random.randint(100, size=300)

expected = np.empty(shape=(a.size, b.size, c.size), dtype=bool)
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for j, y in enumerate(b):
        for k, z in enumerate(c):
            expected[i, j, k] = x < y < z
```

The above triple loop is to show how the expect result should emerge but of course I'd like to use vectorized statements. For doing so I came up with the following two expressions:

```
result1 = (a[:, None] < b)[:, :, None] & (b[:, None] < c)[None, :, :]
result2 = (a[:, None, None] < b[:, None]) & (b[None, :, None] < c[None, :])
```

Both involve a lot of reshaping and inserting extra dimensions and are not really obvious or expressive. I feel like there should be a more concise way to achieve this, I've been looking into [`np.ufunc.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) but I couldn't figure out how to use it for that purpose since when performing the `&` the two operands should share an axis.

**Scaling to arbitrary number of arrays:** As an additional question I'd like to ask whether there's a concise way of scaling the above operation to an arbitrary number of one-dimensional arrays, for example `a < b < c < d < ... < g` for each combination of elements, e.g. given a list of `arrays`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.ix_` is convenient here:

```
A,B,C = np.ix_(a,b,c)
(A<B)&(B<C)
```

arbitrary number of arrays:

```
l = [np.random.randint(10*i, size=i) for i in range(2,6)]
L = np.ix_(*l)
np.bitwise_and.reduce(list(map(np.less, L, L[1:])))
```

or using `functools` (a bit faster)

```
import functools as ft
ft.reduce(np.bitwise_and, map(np.less, L, L[1:]))
```